# single authentication using token

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I have 2 websites hosted in different domians, website 1 and website 2.
The website1 use a  form authentication and it is developed by an external provider. 
The website 2 is accessible only if the user has already authenticated in the website1.
The website 2 is developed using ASP .NET webform.
The website 2 gets an encrypted token for a given user using my web api.
In my website 2 I have to check if the token is valid to authenticate the user. Can you please explaine me how can i implement this SSO and how can I test it. 
Thanks.

Comment: check out oauth and openid connect

Comment: Can you please explaine how can I acheive  that using my webapi

Comment: Use a Security Token Service like Identity Server, to authenticate users for both the applications. Then you do not have to explicity do any authentication/ validation of the users. The STS will take care of that.

Comment: but the website 1 has its own authentication and and I can not change it